# How to change the width and height of my stage dynamically in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've been reading alot of question and I found how to change de the width and height of my stage in AS3:

```
[SWF(backgroundColor="#000000", width="200", height="400", frameRate="29")]
```

The only probleme is that I need to be able to change it while my code is running, because when my app start, according on if it's a student or a teacher that use it, the size of the swf will change.

How can I do that?

Comment: If it's for the web you use javascript to resize the element and change the size of the swf. If it's for Desktop AIR you can too in a limited way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the width and height properties of the Stage using code, it is set to what you provide it when the SWF starts. As far as I know, **stage.stageWidth** and **stage.stageHeight** are read-only properties.

The dimensions of the stage can be different if you set the scale mode properly and let the user change the size using the mouse, but you cannot reassign them to different values dynamically.

You should ideally look at publishing two separate SWF's if your content and size is different for different users.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is inexact but for some reason is already accepted as the right answer. PO did not specify for which platform the question is directed at. On some platform like for the web changing the size of the stage is possible which make your whole answer simply false.

Comment: Good point there :) I agree that my answer may not cater to all scenarios, but is the general answer whenever some one asks about changing the stage dimensions, and plus you are correct, platform was never mentioned. But again, fair point sir!